# How to click on UiObject2?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-uiautomator

I'm using Compose and I have extremely simple app with one Button and Text. When you click button the text changes. I wanted to write tests for this using UiAutomator but I'm experiencing weird behavior. This (with hardcoded position of a button) **works fine**:

```
val uiDevice = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation())
val textObject = uiDevice.findObject(By.res(textId))
uiDevice.click(1233, 250)
assert(textObject.text.equals("Button clicked!"))
```

but this one **fails**:

```
val uiDevice = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation())
val textObject = uiDevice.findObject(By.res(textId))
val buttonObject = uiDevice.findObject(By.res(buttonId))
buttonObject.click()
assert(textObject.text.equals("Button clicked!"))
```

I even tried adding sleeps, waits and all kind of stuff but `buttonObject.click()` just simply doesn't do anything. The type of `buttonObject` is `UiObject2`.